# PHP - Searching for multiple rows with numbers/commas

Tags: php, mysql

I've made a user group and a user table in my database, called `test` and `user_test`. Every user has a field called `groups` which countains at least one number, but could also contain multiple numbers, for example `1,2,3`. The user group table exists of `id` and `group_name`.

What I've been trying to do for so long now is to get data from all groups that this user is assigned to. For example, if one user is assigned to groups `1,2,3` (as its shown in the database), it will print out the name of each group with those id. So perhaps it'd print out `group 1` `group 2` `group 3`.

```
$user_test = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT user_id,groups FROM user_test WHERE user_id = '1'");
while($user_test_fetch = $user_test->fetch_array()) {
    $groups = $user_test_fetch["groups"];
}

if(strlen($groups) > 1) { // user has more than 1 group
    // ???
} else { // user does not have more than 1 group
    $search = "id = '".$groups . "'";
}

$group_data = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE ".$search."");
while($group_data_fetch = $group_data->fetch_array()) {
    echo $group_data_fetch["group_name"];
}
```

Or if you have any other way you'd do this task, please feel free to show me! I'm just simply trying to learn how to do this task (preferably, as efficient as possible).

Comment: Can you modify your database schema? Storing multiple values in one column almost always leads to headaches.

Comment: @Chris No, sorry. I want to know how to do this in this way.

Comment: Normalise your schema. Save yourself a world of pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple.
If it is stored in the `1,2,3` format. And assuming a single one is called `1` and id is an `INT` or `BIGINT` (otherwise this query will slow down if it is a `VARCHAR`)

Change

```
if(strlen($groups) > 1) { // user has more than 1 group
// ???
} else { // user does not have more than 1 group
$search = "id = '".$groups . "'";
}
```

to

```
$search = "id IN (".$groups.");
```

this single line will work with a single group or a set of groups, as long as it is separated by a comma (Because SQL loves commas)

Comment: You learn something new every day! Thanks for the answer. I guess my knowledge within SQL just wasn't big enough! I will mark this as the correct answer in a few minutes :)